# How to compare two DataTables and returns records with only the unmatching data

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to compare two DataTables TableA and TableB.

For Example:

TableA has 7 columns and  5 rows. Currency column is the primary key 
TableB 5 columns and  3 rows. Currency column is the primary key

I want to compare Table1A's each rows data against TableB's rows data using the currency and display only the rows with un matching data (U pto the column Rate4)
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: @Siva, I am trying to loop through TableA and getting the currency code. Using the currency, retreiving the corresponding records from TableB and comparing the Data. This works, but the code is looking very bad. I mean in the real table, total number columns are close to 20

Comment: Post your piece of code

Comment: @ I want to  use Linq instaed of foreach loop that I am using now. STill you want the DataTable Foreach code? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var q = from a in dtA.AsEnumerable()
        join b in dtB.AsEnumerable()
          on a.Field<string>("Currency") equals b.Field<string>("Currency")

        where a.Field<double>("Rate1") != b.Field<double>("Rate1") || 
              a.Field<double>("Rate2") != b.Field<double>("Rate2") || ....

        select new 
        {
            Currency = a.Field<string>("Currency"),
            Rate1    = a.Field<double>("Rate1") == b.Field<double>("Rate1") ? 
                           0 : a.Field<double>("Rate1"),
            Rate2    = a.Field<double>("Rate2") == b.Field<double>("Rate2") ? 
                           0 : a.Field<double>("Rate2"),
            ...
        };
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I will test your solution and post the result ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tableA = new DataTable();
tableA.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate1", typeof(decimal));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate2", typeof(decimal));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate3", typeof(decimal));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate4", typeof(decimal));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate5", typeof(decimal));
tableA.Columns.Add("Rate6", typeof(decimal));

tableA.Rows.Add("USD", 1m, 2m, 3m, 4m, 5.5m, 4.5m);
tableA.Rows.Add("JPY", 1.11m, 4.1m, 3.3m, 4.6m, 5.5m, 3.3m);
tableA.Rows.Add("GBP", 3.0m, 1m, 3m, 4m, 7.7m, 8.8m);
tableA.Rows.Add("EUR", 3.0m, 1m, 3m, 4m, 7.7m, 8.8m);
tableA.Rows.Add("MXN", 3.0m, 1m, 3m, 4m, 7.7m, 8.8m);


var tableB = new DataTable();
tableB.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
tableB.Columns.Add("Rate1", typeof(decimal));
tableB.Columns.Add("Rate2", typeof(decimal));
tableB.Columns.Add("Rate3", typeof(decimal));
tableB.Columns.Add("Rate4", typeof(decimal));

tableB.Rows.Add("USD", 1m, 2m, 3m, 4m);
tableB.Rows.Add("JPY", 1.11m, 9.9m, 3.3m, 4.6m);
tableB.Rows.Add("GBP", 3m, 1m, 3m, 4m);

var query = from r1 in tableA.AsEnumerable()
            from r2 in tableB.AsEnumerable()
            where
                r1.Field<string>("Currency") == r2.Field<string>("Currency")

            && r1.Field<decimal>("Rate1") == r2.Field<decimal>("Rate1")
            && r1.Field<decimal>("Rate2") == r2.Field<decimal>("Rate2")
            && r1.Field<decimal>("Rate3") == r2.Field<decimal>("Rate3")
            && r1.Field<decimal>("Rate4") == r2.Field<decimal>("Rate4")
    select r2;

var result = tableB.AsEnumerable().Except(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = TableB.Clone();
dt = TableA.AsEnumerable().Join(TableB.AsEnumerable(),
                                row=>row.Field<string>(0),
                                row=>row.Field<string>(0), (a,b)=> new {a,b})
        .Select(pair=> {
          DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
          row.SetField<string>(0, pair.a.Field<string>(0));
          bool notNull = false;
          for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){ 
            var a = pair.a.Field<decimal>(i);
            var b = pair.b.Field<decimal>(i);
            if(a == b) row.SetField<decimal>(i, 0);
            else {
               row.SetField<decimal>(i, Math.Max(a,b));
               notNull = true;
            }
          }
          return notNull ? row : null;
       }).Where(row=>row != null).CopyToDataTable();
```

**NOTE**: I suppose the data type in all the columns `Rate X` is `decimal`, the first column `Currency` is of course `string`.